# Is anime on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We're Science Fiction & Fantasy.  We deal with all forms of speculative fiction.

Does this automatically include anime?  If so, will this change if the [Anime & Manga](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538/anime-manga) proposal launches?

We've had questions about [Naruto](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4383/what-is-the-source-of-gaaras-abilty-to-control-sand) in the past, but there's generally been no activity regarding anime.  It's as if no one in our (relatively small) community knows much about anime, or cares.

Or is anime just another medium, like books, comics, and tv, and we should judge the 'on-topic' factor per series?

Comment: Your underlying worry, about cross-over between different SE sites, will eventually come to a head. However, the current thought is that they should be solved on a case-by-case basis. We'll decide with Anime and Manga what constitutes the line between our two sites when the time comes. :)

Comment: [When the Literature stack exchange site goes live, how do we handle conflicts?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/626)

Answer (score 16):

> Or is anime just another medium, like books, comics, and tv, and we should judge the 'on-topic' factor per series?

This.  Your question breaks down to "is (media) on topic"?  And the answer is, "Yes, if it's Sci-fi or Fantasy."